# Opening a python file and appending specific information

Tags: python-3.x

I have some data data from a txt file that I'm trying to sort into a list  that should look like this:

```
[ALASKA, [2006/10/19, 2.8], [2006/10/18, 2.6], etc etc] 

[MEXICO, [2006/10/20, 2.8], [2006/10/18, 3.3]] for each location without any  tuples or ''


2.8 2006/10/19 02:02:10 62.391 -149.751 15.0 CENTRAL ALASKA

2.5 2006/10/19 00:31:15 20.119 -156.213 1.5 MAUI REGION, HAWAII

5.0 2006/10/18 21:15:51 4.823 -82.592 37.3 SOUTH OF PANAMA

2.6 2006/10/18 21:12:25 59.934 -147.904 30.0 GULF OF ALASKA

3.4 2006/10/18 20:59:21 36.540 -89.640 7.7 SOUTHEASTERN MISSOURI
```

Code:

```
def main():

    file = open('data.txt','r')    
    category1 = [[]]   

    for line in file:
        magnitude, date, time, x, y, z, location = line.strip().split(' ')
        locationend = location.split(' ')[-1]
        category1[locationend].append((date,magnitude))

    #print(category1)

 main()
```

Right now i'm running into an error where the line.split function cannot unpack all 8 pieces of data on each line, is there another way to remove items 3:5? I know its possible being the pop function in a list.

Comment: Please clarify the problem with your code - what's the current output? What should it be instead? As it stands I'd expect an error because there is no `category[1]` when you try to append. Do you want a dictionary `{'ALASKA': [...], ...}` instead?

Comment: You're going to get errors with your `line.split(' ')` assignment, because 3 of the 5 example lines you show have more than 2 "location" words at the end. I also don't understand what the first line of your data is supposed to mean.

Comment: i'm running into the issue where I cant save the magnitude and date as variables from each line because I cannot unpack that many variables without removing the unnecessary data (don't know how to do that in a string). Ideally I'd like it to look like **[ALASKA, [2006/10/19, 2.8], [2006/10/18, 2.6], etc etc] **

Comment: @skryt so all you want is the first two fields of each line, indexed with the very last field in the line?

Comment: @MattDMo Never thought of looking at it that way, but yes just those specific pieces.

Comment: @skryt OK, so do something like `line_contents = line.split()` to put everything from `line` into a list, then access the items using list slicing, remembering that Python is zero-indexed (i.e., the first item is `line_contents[0]`). Create a dict using `line_contents[-1]` as the key, and the value as a list of 2-member lists containing the date (as a string) and the magnitude (as a string or float, your pick).

Answer (score 0):

`str.split` includes an optional `maxsplit` argument that limits the values to split and you can use this to get the entire location name as a single item. Now, you can use a `dict` to gather a list of data per location. `collections.defaultdict` is nice here as it automatically creates values for new keys. Now you have a list of date/magnitude pairs and you can use `itertools.chain` to unpack them as you write. Put it all together and you get

```
import collections
import itertools

def main():
    locations = collections.defaultdict(list)   
    with open('data.txt','r') as file:
        for line in file:
            magnitude, date, time, x, y, z, location = line.strip().split(' ', 6)
            locations[location].append((date, magnitude))
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        for location, data in locations.items():
            outfile.write('{}, {}\n'.format(location, 
                ' ,'.join(itertools.chain.from_iterable(data))))
main()

print(open('output.txt').read())
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses a dictionary to keep lists of each event for each locale:

This is the sample data used since I did not have a file:

```
data = [x.strip() for x in """
    2.8 2006/10/19 02:02:10 62.391 -149.751 15.0 CENTRAL ALASKA
    2.5 2006/10/19 00:31:15 20.119 -156.213 1.5 MAUI REGION, HAWAII
    5.0 2006/10/18 21:15:51 4.823 -82.592 37.3 SOUTH OF PANAMA
    2.6 2006/10/18 21:12:25 59.934 -147.904 30.0 GULF OF ALASKA
    3.4 2006/10/18 20:59:21 36.540 -89.640 7.7 SOUTHEASTERN MISSOURI
    """.split('\n')[1:-1]]
```

This code shows how to go through the data and split it while maintaining the entire location.  After the entire location is discovered, then it is easy to get the last word in the location, and keep a list of each event for that location suffix.  Not that the `6` passed to `split()` forces it to keep everything after the first five fields in one remaining field (location):

```
data_dict = {}
for line in data:
    magnitude, date, time, x, y, z, location = line.split(' ', 6)

    # get the last word in the location
    location_suffix = location.split(' ')[-1]

    # store the event
    if location_suffix not in data_dict:
        data_dict[location_suffix] = []
    data_dict[location_suffix].append((date, magnitude))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
def process(filename):
    d = {}
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            line_contents = line.split()
            if line_contents[-1] in d.keys(): # we already have an entry
                d[line_contents[-1]].append([line_contents[1], line_contents[0]])
            else:
                d[line_contents[-1]] = [[line_contents[1], line_contents[0]]]
    return d
```

You could also have each key's value be a list of tuples if you wish.

Comment: Is it only possible to do with a string using dictionaries/tuples, ive been toying around to format it as a list within a list, but ive been running into trouble with unnecessary punctuation when im appending the items into the list now, ie () and '' around date and magnitude

Comment: @skryt I'm not quite sure what you're asking. My code creates a dictionary with string keys and values of a list of lists, with each inner list containing two strings. So, if you have three entries for Alaska, the dict will look like `{'ALASKA': [['2.6', '2006/10/19'], ['3.7', '2006/11/21'], ['2.4', '2006/12/13']]}`

Comment: Is it only possible to create it as a dictionary, or is it possible to create the entire thing in a list?  [ALASKA , [2.6, 2006/10/19], [3.7, 2006/11/21], [2.4, 2006/12/13]

Comment: @skryt it would be *possible* to create a list of lists, where each inner list has the location as the first element, and subsequent elements are magnitude/date pairs. The problem with that is accessing the data afterwards. How are you going to find the "MEXICO" values, or the "HAWAII" ones? You would first need to search each sublist in the list of lists to find the correct one, get its index, and then use that index to access the other data. With a dict, you can access all the data by using `d["LOCATION"]`, and using further slicing to get the individual data pairs.

Comment: @skryt to add to what I said above, as the results list gets bigger, all that searching will become more and more expensive, whereas with a dict it won't.